# How can I change the last letters of a word in a different language?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, hebrew

I need my code to recognize specific letters in Hebrew at the end of words and then replace them with their form as final letters.
For example: כ=ך,מ=ם,נ=ן,פ=ף,צ=ץ.
I attempted doing this with the following bit of code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from string import maketrans

text = "לנמנמ זה כיפ"
textSplit = text.split()
translator = maketrans("כמנפצ","ךםןףץ")
correctSpelling = ""

for i in textSplit:
    if i[-1]=="כ" or i[-1]=="מ":
        correctSpelling += i.translate(translator) + " "
    else:
        correctSpelling += i + " "

print correctSpelling
```

Output: לנמנמ זה כיפ.
Expected output: לנמנם זה כיף.
There are no errors with the above code.
After reading [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), [Overcoming frustration: Correctly using unicode in python2](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html), and The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) it's time to ask stackoverflow.

Comment: So, are you getting an error, or...?

Comment: Please expand on the question, including any errors you're receiving, as well as expected vs actual output.

Comment: looks like you mixed up your call to `maketrans` by switching your `intab` and `outtab` parameters. ie you should have `translator = maketrans('abc','123')` if you want `a` to be replaced by `1`, `b` by `2`, etc.

Comment: The order of the maketrans is fine in the original code, here it changed it to right to left.

Comment: The answer is actually the *very first paragraph* of the 2nd article you linked.

Comment: Which part exactly? @roeland

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong data type. In Python 2, strings (like `'abc'`) are for bytes, and unicode (like `u'abc'`) is for text.

So:

```
# wrong (putting unicode characters in byte literals is ill-defined):
ord("צ");
# correct:
ord(u"צ");
```

(Python 3 reverses this, `'abc'` is unicode and bytes have an explicit `b` prefix)

Comment: Thanks! This did point me in the right direction although the solution didn't really have anything to do with ord and chr in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use Unicode strings everywhere, along with a Unicode translation table that maps Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals.  This version will work in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

text = u"לנמנמ זה כיפ"

textSplit = text.split()
translator = {ord(a):ord(b) for a,b in zip(u"כמנפצ",u"ךםןףץ")}
correctSpelling = u""
print(u"כפצנמ".translate(translator)) #just a test for the translator

for i in textSplit:
    if i[-1]==u"כ" or i[-1]==u"מ" or i[-1]==u"נ" or i[-1]==u"פ" or i[-1]==u"צ":
        correctSpelling += i[:-1] + i[-1].translate(translator) + u" "
    else:
        correctSpelling += i + " "

print(correctSpelling)
```

Output:

```
ךףץןם
לנמנם זה כיף
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode strings to represent text.

Here's a single source Python 2/3 compatible code that use a regular expression to replace the last letters with their form as final letters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import re

text = "לנמנמ זה כיפ"

final_letters = dict(zip(map(ord, "כמנפצ"),"ךםןףץ"))
print(re.sub(r'\w\b', lambda m: m.group().translate(final_letters), text,
             flags=re.UNICODE))
```

#### Output

```
לנמנם זה כיף
```

The code works despite appearances of the parens (it might be some right-to-left related issue).

Answer (score -1):

After tinkering with my code another few times (read: hours), I found what the problem was.
Apparently two things were wrong in my code: first I presumed that the encoding was utf-8 already, and secondly I thought that .translate(translator) would work with unicode data type.
To solve the first problem I added this bit:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

After that was out of the way I changed the text to unicode data type (instead of str) and revised some of the code like this:

```
if i[-1]=="כ" or i[-1]=="מ" or i[-1]=="נ" or i[-1]=="פ" or i[-1]=="צ":
        correctSpelling += i[:-1] + str(i[-1]).translate(translator) + " "
```

So here is the code in full after revising:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from string import maketrans
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

#the text is of data type unicode
text = u"לנמנמ זה כיפ"

textSplit = text.split()
translator = maketrans("כמנפצ","ךםןףץ")
correctSpelling = ""
print "כפצנמ".translate(translator) #just a test for the translator

for i in textSplit:
    if i[-1]=="כ" or i[-1]=="מ" or i[-1]=="נ" or i[-1]=="פ" or i[-1]=="צ":
        correctSpelling += i[:-1] + str(i[-1]).translate(translator) + " "
    else:
        correctSpelling += i + " "

print correctSpelling
```

output:

```
ךףץןם
לנמנם זה כיף
```

Comment: The `reload(sys)` trick is not the solution.  There's a reason `setdefaultencoding` doesn't work without the trick.  I'll add an answer that avoids the trick.

Comment: This answer mixes bytestrings (sequence of bytes) and Unicode strings (sequence of Unicode code points) that is why you have to hack `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. Don't do it, use Unicode to represent text e.g., as I've shown in my answer.